Django decorator and middleware issue
My decorator looks like this
def require_feature(feature_name):
    def decorator(view_func):
        print(f"process_view - view_func: {view_func}")  # Debugging

        @wraps(view_func)
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

        _wrapped_view.required_feature = feature_name
        return _wrapped_view

    return decorator

and the middleware looks like this
class EntitlementMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response) -> None:
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request) -> Any:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            request.user.features = get_user_features(request.user)
        else:
            request.user.features = []
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        print(f"process_view - view_func: {view_func}")  # Debugging
        required_feature = getattr(view_func, "required_feature", None)
        if required_feature and not request.user.features.filter(name=required_feature):
            raise PermissionDenied("You do not have access to this feature")

        return None  # if none is returned then view is called normally

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        return response

and this is how I am using it in my viewset
class MyViewSet(ValidatePkMixin, viewsets.ViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = My.objects.all()

    @method_decorator(require_feature("Basic"))
    def list(self, request):
      pass

the decorator sets the required_feature when server starts.
the middleware gets called when I make a /get call but this
required_feature = getattr(view_func, "required_feature", None)

returns None
what am I missing here?

The method isn't directly hooked up as view function; you're getting some dispatch function of the viewset class, which will internally call list eventually.

If I'm not wrong, the middleware in DJango always run first.
Like this: request coming -> middleware -> decorator -> main function. So in middleware cannot have required_feature which is set in decorator.

@ThànhLý A decorator modifies a function at time of declaration. If the function/method/class "physically" exists, the decorator has taken effect. It does that once when the code is loaded, and the effect then exists until you stop Django. The decoration does not take place on every request.

It might make sense to add "entitlements" to the active user in a middleware, but the permission checking should be implemented as a custom permission checker on the view.

@deceze - right now we check permission in view agree. My opinion it is not correct, if user dont have permissions - request should not goes in view. I prefer use url_protector. it runned before .as_view()

so it seems I can not use middleware to check for the attribute set by the decorator...is it correct? Though the decorator code gets executed as soon I start the server and it adds the attr but somehow it is not available in the middleware

you try to reinvent the user.permissions, I add it in my answer

You are check from middleware function(method) dispatch which will be called from middleware. And you decorate completely other function(method) list.
in Django, if you work with Generic CBVs or ViewSets request goes through middlewares, and through Class.as_view() the request-dispatcher will be returned.
For both - for  Generic CBVs and for ViewSets it is:
class View:
    ...
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return handler # exactly here will be called your cls.list 
    ...

But right now i see, you want reinvent user permissions/permission classes.
The best way for you goal is - to create child class from BasePermission.
More here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/
You want to catch all requests on middleware level. For that DRF offer you settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES:
#settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'myapp.permissions.IsFeatured',
    ]
}

This class check "feature" by user for choosen handler. BTW I still don't understand, why you don't use custom user.permissions.
After you need the permission class:
#myapp/permissions.py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class IsFeatured(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        handler = getattr(view, view.action)
        feature = getattr(handler, "required_feature", None)
        if feature:
            return request.user.features.filter(name=feature).exists()
        return True

Thats all. It should work as you want, but i dont check it on errors. BTW, this solution repeated already existed solution to work with user.permission

Can you please elaborate your answer?

welcome, i extend it.
